# how to save a list as template to download which has exceeds the treshold of 5000

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, list-view

maxx threshold : 5000 in the system

I like to download a list view (save as template) which I like to check the code in SPD. When I try to open in SPD directly it says threshold, then I thought I should save the list and download the file to my test environment and eventually increase the threshold there (I'm alone on that machine :), it also says "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enfored by the administrator." Then I used filters just taking 23 records in the listview filter... it still doesn't allow me.

so how can I save the list as template to able to download the file?

I can not change the threshold value in Central Admin --> I asked they don't do it! So what other solution can I do?